# Formatting Dynamic Array of Bits as String in SystemVerilog

Tags: arrays, system-verilog, dynamic-arrays

How can I format a dynamic array of bits (or more correctly, logics) as a string, e.g., for UVM's convert2string?  For example, I would like to convert

```
logic        vdyn[];  
...  
vdyn = new [16] ('{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1});
```

to the string `0097`.

I thought the following would work (the `#` are just to delimit the string for readability):

```
  fmt = $sformatf("#%%%0dh#", (vdyn.size-1)/4 + 1); // "#%4h#"
  vstr = $sformatf(fmt, { >> {vdyn}});
```

but it returns `#   x#`, at least in Questa 10.3d (I suspect this is a bug - I'd be interested if it works on other simulators).

I tried converting it to a packed array first, but that runs into other problems.  Without a size constraint on the result, the source value always gets left-justified in the destination variable, e.g.:

```
logic [63:0] v64;
...
v64 = {>> {vdyn}}; // 64'h0097000000000000
```

There's no way to print out just the part I want without using variable-size slices.  The following works, but it requires that I know the size of the array at compile time:

```
v64 = 16'({>> {vdyn}});  // 64'h0000000000000097
```

The best thing I've found is the following "double-reverse" (note that I'm using `<<` here, not `>>`):

```
     v64 = {<< {vdyn}};    // 64'he900000000000000 
     v64 = {<< {v64}};     // 64'h0000000000000097
     vstr = $sformatf(fmt, v64); // #0097#
```

It seems kind of hokey to have to do this, though.  By the way, combining the first two statements into one doesn't work:

```
     v64 = {<< {{<< {vdyn}}}};     // 64'hZ900000000000000
```

(`v64[63]` is `z` for some reason).  Again, I suspect this is a bug in Questa 10.3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting a slice of the array and loop through. For example an 4 entry slice that is cast to a 4-bits value. A slize can be done with the `-:` or `+:` operator (See [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 7.4.3 *Operations on arrays* and § 7.4.6 *Indexing and slicing of arrays*)

```
vstr = "";
for(int i=vdyn.size()-1; i>=0; i-=4) begin
  vstr = $sformatf("%h%s", 4'({>>{vdyn[i -: 4]}}), vstr);
end
vstr = $sformatf("#%s#", vstr); // user formatting
```

The `4`s in the code can be changed to something else depending how much leading 0 or a non-power-of-two formatting is desired, but it must be a numeric constant

---

I tried your code on some other simulators. `vstr = $sformatf(fmt, { >> {vdyn}});` sometimes gave me compiling errors. Casting the array to something bigger than its expected max size seems to work

```
fmt = $sformatf("#%%%0dh#", (vdyn.size-1)/4 + 1); // "#%4h#"
vstr = $sformatf(fmt, 128'({ >> {vdyn}})); // works iff 128>=vdyn.size
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought about doing it with a loop (I generally write VHDL, so I'm used to doing things the brute-force way).  I think it would need a little enhancement to support sizes that aren't a multiple of 4, but otherwise it should work for virtually any size array.  Streaming to a packed array (like I did) still puts an upper limit on the size.  Thanks for trying the code on another simulator.  Casting it to a fixed size "works" on Questa 10.3d, but it has the same left-justification problem I mentioned.

Comment: I played with it non-multiples of 4 and it still casts correctly with the simulators on [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/) after changing `i>0` to `i>=0`. Example: `vdyn = new [17]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that the width of the streaming operator using dynamic types is not defined in a self-determined context (e.g. an argument to a system task). I think the LRM should have treated this an error.

A work-around is to shift the left-justified result to the right by

```
v64 = {>> {vdyn}}; 
v64 >>= 64-vdyn.size;
```

Comment: (a) The width should be unambiguous, although obviously not static (if that's what you meant by "self-determined").  
(b) That's a little bit saner way to change the justification, but is there really no way to directly convert a dynamic array of bits to the equivalent (right-justified) packed array?  Seems to me like that would be an obvious language feature. (c) Is there any way to add line breaks in a comment on here?  I just noticed that everything runs together into one paragraph.

Comment: Yes. I should have said _not statically defined_. Verilog requires the width of all integral types to be statically determined.